# are theses phrases similar in sense?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

learning English I keep trying to translate what I think in my native language to english all the time.

When I wake up most of times my voice is hoarse, and I use to test my voice before I send some voice message via WhatsApp. So that is the context:

I said in English in my head these phrases:

1 - morning vocal test.

2 - test morning voice ("test" being noun, and "morning voice" also noun)

3 - morning test voice ("morning" as noun, "test voice" also noun)

do they all make sense? and means the same?

Comment: Can you edit to clarify what exactly you want them to mean?

Comment: @mdewey, I want to know if phrases:1,2 &3 convey the same message

Comment: (2) and (3) don't work as noun phrases, but you could say _morning voice test_, where _morning_ and _voice_ are nouns acting as adjectives modifying _test_. NB We don't say _I use to_ in the present tense. _I always/usually/generally test my voice_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, helpful answer. But they all mean the same, right?

Comment: They're all just strings of nouns. How are they supposed to mean anything? As compound nouns, they do not mean the same thing, if that's what you're asking. The first is a test, while the other two are a voice.

Comment: They don't 'all mean the same' because (2) and (3) don't make sense, as I indicated. (As gotube says, they sound like nonsensical descriptions of a voice, not a test.)

Comment: @all I see your point, but as i mentioned in description of the question I'm testing my voice in the morning, so shouldn't number 2 make any sense? it should be a description of a voice right?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, don't you think we could save number (2)? I mean "morning voice" is a description of someone voice in the morning after wake up, usually hoarse. So the "test" in the beginning is to describe a test of a voice when weke up (in the morning)

Comment: If you want it to be a noun phrase like (1), it would have to be 'test of my morning voice'.